# How to use IDisposable Interface(not disposing inner objects)

Tags: vb.net, idisposable

First of all thanks and Pardon me if my English is not good.
   I tried a lot to get how to implement IDisposable Interface. As per pictures i got from net i implemented the interface. In my test project i tried a lot so if i'm loading some image to memory i could see IDisposible works as per my expectation.To see the memory(PF Usage) I used task manager.Here "test.bmp" is 5mb file

These are the three experiments i have done

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While (i < 1000)
        i = i + 1
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap("D:\test.bmp")
    End While
```

It killed my memory.  Then i tried

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While (i < 1000)
        i = i + 1
        Using bmp As New Bitmap("D:\test.bmp")
        End Using
    End While
```

PF was steady until the 1000. Means memory released propery.

then i tried

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    While (i < 1000)
        i = i + 1
        Using oTestDispose As New clsTestDispose
        End Using
    End While
Public Class clsTestDispose
Implements IDisposable

Dim bmp As New Bitmap("D:\test.bmp")

Private disposedValue As Boolean = False        ' To detect redundant calls

' IDisposable
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources when explicitly called
            Me.Dispose()
        End If

        ' TODO: free shared unmanaged resources
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
End Sub

#Region " IDisposable Support "
' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)        above.
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub
#End Region

 End Class
```

This code is telling "System.StackOverFlowException". Why the dispose is not clearing the image object inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are overriding the `Dispose` method and calling it again inside with `Me.Dispose`, this method runs recursively.

You could call `Dispose` with `MyBase:

```
MyBase.Dispose()
```

This will call the `Dispose` on the derived class, preventing it to loop and end in a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you Patrick A lot. I'm marking this as the answer of my question. But my actual problem is still not solved. When I'm commenting calling dispose() method. It is killing my memory and making "Out of Memory Exception". How can i clean the memory more properly? In other words in real coding lot of objects will get generated inside an object. If the container object disposes how can i clear the inner objects?

Comment: Microsoft does this in generated code by keeping a list of active Controls and call the `Dispose` on them after use. The controls themselves should forward this to their children if relevant. Your second sample was the most accurate one and should work fine (this is how it is intended to be).

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me clear about the concept. So I need to release all the memory manually even if using dispose also. In dispose method needs the logic of each and every object cleaning that.Right?So dispose don't have any magic other than standardisation. Am i right?

Comment: That's true. If you have a Control for example you may rely on the `Form` to dispose that properly. If you have a variable Bitmap in the Control you have to dispose it 'yourself' by putting it in the `Dispose` of your control.